# What does the SwiftUI `@State` keyword do?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

The [SwiftUI tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input) uses the `@State` keyword to indicate mutable UI state:

`@State var showFavoritesOnly = false`

It offers this summary:

> State is a value, or a set of values, that can change over time, and that affects a view’s behavior, content, or layout. You use a property with the @State attribute to add state to a view.

- What does the keyword mean, exactly?
- How does mutating a `@State` variable cause the view to be recomputed?
- How are other variables immutable within the `body` getter?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson you can't expect nobody asks questions about new technology

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The `@State` keyword is a `@propertyWrapper`, a feature just recently introduced in Swift 5.1. As explained in the [corresponding proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md), it's sort of a value wrapper avoiding boilerplate code.

---

*Sidenote: `@propertyWrapper` has previously been called `@propertyDelegate`, but that has changed since. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56510768/difference-between-propertydelegate-and-propertywrapper) for more information.*

---

The [official @State documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) has the following to say:

> `SwiftUI` **manages the storage** of any property you declare as a state.
>   **When the state value changes, the view invalidates its appearance and
>   recomputes the body**. Use the state as the single source of truth for a
>   given view.
>
> **A State instance isn’t the value itself; it’s a means of
>   reading and mutating the value**. To access a state’s underlying value,
>   use its value property.

So when you initialize a property that's marked `@State`, you're not actually  creating your own variable, but rather prompting `SwiftUI` to create *"something"* in the background that stores what you set and monitors it from now on! Your `@State var` just acts as a **delegate to access this wrapper**.

Every time your `@State` variable is **written**, `SwiftUI` will know as it is monitoring it. It will also know whether the `@State` variable was **read** from the `View`'s `body`. Using this information, it will be able to **recompute any `View`** having referenced a `@State` variable in its `body` after a change to this variable.

Comment: Are they still called property delegates or is it property wrapper now? Maybe both :(

Comment: This is good info, but how does this actually work: "When the state value changes, the view invalidates its appearance and recomputes the body"? In the Integrating video the Italian guy says that SwiftUI knows that the state property is used in the body, and that it also knows which view it is in. I don't see how this is possible, do you?

Comment: @23inhouse I've added clarification about this to my post. TLDR: They mean the same, but `@propertyWrapper` is preferred.

Comment: @Gusutafu As a `@propertyWrapper` is a wrapper, it does not only know when it's written, but also when it's read – this way, it can figure out from which views it is read. I've added clarification about this to my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Let me add something else if you know React Native.

The `@State` property is very like the `this.state` object in React Native.

For example:

```swift
struct Foobar: some View {
    @State var username = ""
}
```

```
class Foobar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
    };
  }
}
```

When you modify the username variable, they will have the same effect, that re-render the current page.

Comment: Does SwiftUi have props?

Comment: [@Lee Irvine] Yea, but not the same, the constructor parameters are equivalent to the `props` object.  Because they all come from their parent control/component.

Answer (score 6):

Its explained nicely with an example in the [WWDC video - Session 204](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/204/) (starts at 16:00, quotation starts at 20:15)

> One of the special properties of `@State` variables is that SwiftUI can observe when they're read and written. Because SwiftUI knows that `zoomed` was read in `body`, it knows that the view's rendering depends on it. Which means - when a variable changes the framework is going to ask for `body` again using the new `@State` value.

The `@State` as a Property Wrapper is also elaborated and justified in [Data Flow Through Swift UI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/) (5:38) WWDC vid as well. It's shown how it solves the problem when we need a mutable value in an immutable (`struct`) `View`.

Comment: "Because SwiftUI knows that zoomed was read in body" - What mechanism in Swift makes this possible?

Comment: @Gusutafu The Combine framework (publish and subscribe). SwiftUI provides the subscriber, so it hears every time the publisher sends out a message that the variable has changed. In response, it calls `body` to get the interface generate afresh.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing I was struggling with was more _how_ SwiftUI or the State itself could possibly know that the State is used in a _particular_ body!

Answer (score 3):

If you click into `@State` you can see that it has several getters.  One with `Value` another with `Binding<Value>`.
SwiftUI seems to rely heavily on reactive programming (and their new `Combine` framework, and since we cannot see the full implementation of these wrappers, I would expect that the values that are stored through `@State` property wrappers are being managed by a `CurrentValueSubject` from `Combine`.  Like the name implies, this essentially stores the current value, which can then be used as a bindable property by using the `$` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

I like how profesor Paul Hegarty from Stanford explains it. He said that `@State` basically converts that variable into a pointer to some boolean somewhere else in memory and that's where the value changes. But your variable - now a pointer with `@State`- does not change, it is always pointing to that place in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Note:- The accepted answer is correct but incase you are trying to look for a easier explanation I tried below

---

**@State** property wrapper allow us to change values inside a struct.

**Note**:- You cannot change a property within a struct as its a values types, so its not allowed.

```
struct ExampleTextView: View {

    // Declare a variable with state property wrapper
    @State private var shouldChangeText: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Just an example")
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    }
}
```

- **Incase you are wondering should we add a private access specifier?**

  Yes, as a rule of thumb apple recommends @State propertise shouldn't be
  shared with other views as there are more specific property wrappers for
  that @ObservedObject and @EnvironmentObject.
- **But if it's value type how it can be mutated where is it stored then?**

  So whenever we are marking a property with @State we move its storage out
  from the struct into the shared storage managed by SwiftUI.

**In case in your mind if you are comparing with Swift, this is how its done there,**

```
struct Example {
    var exampleType: String
    
    mutating func changeType() {
        exampleType = "Are we allowed to do this?"
    }
}
```

Credit: Please note this answer is inspired by this post https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-state-property-wrapper

Answer (score 0):

If you know about C# and windows development. `@State` is similar if not the same as `x:Bind` or `Binding`.. On a collection it is similar if not the same as `ObservableCollection`.

As fredpi said, SwiftUI is listing for updates on vars with the `@State` property delegate.