# What is the property / $property syntax for bindings?

Tags: swift, swiftui

As seen in the [handling user input tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input).

```swift
struct LandmarkList: View {
    @State var showFavoritesOnly = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Toggle(isOn: $showFavoritesOnly) {
                    Text("Favorites only")
                }
   ...
```

What is the showFavoritesOnly / $showFavoritesOnly syntax ?

Is it something unique to `Binding<T>` or can we use it in our own code ?

Comment: Read about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56438730/what-does-the-swiftui-state-keyword-do

Answer (score 2):

`@State` is designed to be used as a binding for SwiftUI properties. Any access to it outside the `body` accessor of your `View` will crash with:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Accessing State<Bool> outside View.body
```

SwiftUI automatically tracks all the `@State` declarations and re-calculates the appropriate `body` whenever any of them change.

`@State` is implemented using the Swift 5.1 `@propertyDelegate` feature, which enables the storage behavior of properties to be customized.

Comment: thanks for the info. I looked into it and seems that the $ syntax is available for any `@propertyDelegate`. It returns the object that stores the value

Comment: Since the body gets recalculated, why do you yse the $ syntax and not the value of the state property? Wouldn't that do the same?