# Setting a @State var from another view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, state

I am trying to set the value of a `@State` var in var `a` of struct `A` from a var `b` of struct `B`, but it doesn't work.  I need to use a `@State` var because I am passing it as a binding.  Ex:

```
struct A : View {
  @State var myBindableVar = ""
  var body : some View {
     TextField(self.$myBindableVar) ...
  }
}

struct B : View {
  @State var a : A
  var body : some View {
     Button(action: { self.a.myBindableVar = "???" }) { ... }
  }
}
```

`myBindableVar` isn't set to `"???"` when the button is tapped.  Why?

Comment: [Understanding @State and @Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56488929/understanding-binding-in-swiftui)... and search by keywords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use @Binding to achieve this. Here is some example code. I let View B appear inside View A so that you can directly see the working result on screen:

```
struct A : View {
  @State var myBindableVar = ""
  var body : some View {
    VStack {
     Text(myBindableVar)
    Spacer()
    B(myBindableVar: $myBindableVar)
    }
  }
}

struct B : View {
  @Binding var myBindableVar : String
  var body : some View {
    Button(action: { self.myBindableVar = "Text appears" }) {
        Text("Press to change")
    }
  }
}
```