# SwiftUI: Calling a mutating func in a struct from a View body throws 'immutable value' error

Tags: swiftui, struct, boolean, mutating-function

I like to change a var in a struct from a View body. However, this throws in 'immutable value' error each time. After Googling, a `mutating func` seems appropriate, but also this method throws the same error.

Minimum reproducible example below (tap the button > toggle the Bool in the struct > change the button color).

Note that in my original code it's not about changing the button color, but marking a quiz module as complete and updating some interface items and colors.

```
// Module.swift

import SwiftUI

struct Module: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var complete: Bool
    
    mutating func toggleComplete() {
        complete.toggle()
    }
}

var modules = [
    Module(title: "Module 1", complete: false)
    Module(title: "Module 2", complete: false)
]
```

```
// ModuleButton.swift

import SwiftUI

struct ModuleButton: View {
    var module: Module
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(module.title){}
            .padding(8)
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            .background(module.complete ? .green : .blue)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous))
            .onTapGesture{
                module.toggleComplete()
            }
    }
}

struct ModuleButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ModuleButton(module: modules[0])
    }
}
```

Some examples of how I got inspired to use `mutating func`:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/7/5/mutating-methods

https://chris.eidhof.nl/post/structs-and-mutation-in-swift/

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/654058

Comment: `module` should be `@State`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, `module` should be an [`@State`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) variable. Here's a question explaining what `@State` is: [What does the SwiftUI `@State` keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56438730/what-does-the-swiftui-state-keyword-do). See the question for more information on the background behind `@State`. Here's how you should modify your code:

```swift
struct ModuleButton: View {
    @State var module: Module //<<<--- Here!!!
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(module.title){}
            .padding(8)
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            .background(module.complete ? .green : .blue)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous))
            .onTapGesture{
                //This now works
                module.toggleComplete()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction and explanation, it works indeed! I tried to add @State to multiple variables inside the struct, but obviously your suggestion is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

`var module` should be `@Binding` when you want write access, ie do a mutation, eg

```
struct ModuleButton: View {
    @Binding var module: Module
```

In Views that only read it should just be `let`.

In both cases when the View is init with a value different from last time, body will be called.

It might be helpful to know that `@Binding` is simply convenience for a pair of get/set closures.